# Android actionbar icons always in overflow

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-4.4-kitkat, android-menu, overflow-menu

I declared my menu items with `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"`. My Activity is extending `ActionBarActivity`. In preview it is as expected but when run on my phone is it always in overflow.

From what I've seen nothing else is needed. My phone runs in `Android 4.4.2 KitKat`.

Am I missing anything else?

Comment: Please post your menu resource.

Comment: Could this be by design, because the phone screen is just to small? What happens if you use "always"? @CommonsWare is right, some more info would be useful.

Comment: @RolfSmit No, it's because aambrozkiewicz is using ActionBarCompat and you have to use a custom namespace, if you want to use attributes, that were introduced in newer versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define your own namespace, if you want to use the `showAsAction` attribute with `ActionBarCompat`(I assume you are using `ActionBarCompat` because you mentioned, that you're extending `ActionBarActivity`):

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

and use `showAsAction` like this:

```
<item [...] app:showAsAction="always"></item>
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I had that namespace but tried to use android:showAsAction.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this...

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_blah"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_c"
    android:title="@string/action_blah"
    app:showAsAction="(yourOptions)"/>
```

**`(yourOptions)`**:

1. always = To force to show on the actionbar.
2. never = Not to show on your actionbar ever.
   and
3. ifRoom = It will let your item if there is enough space on your action bar.

You can see these in Landscape mode.

*HappyCoding*